# I am trying to run a psipred command, but it shos an error that "Unmatched '`'. '

Tags: linux, database, csh, tcsh, blast

I ran a psipred command of pgenthreade.sh script:

```
tcsh psipred /media/kakarot/ppi/genthreader/sequence.iter3.mtx /media/kakarot/ppi/psipred/data/weights.dat /media/kakarot/ppi/psipred/data/weights.dat2 /media/kakarot/ppi/psipred/data/weights.dat3 > /media/kakarot/ppi/genthreader/sequence.pgen.ss
```

It results in:

> **Unmatched '`'.**

Comment: Why do you want to use `tcsh`? The `psipred` is a csh-script?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. Nobody can answer questions about unknown code.

Comment: @uzsolt It is a binary file: https://github.com/psipred/psipred/blob/master/bin/psipred

Comment: Remove "tcsh" from your command and call the program directly. Make sure, that it is executable ("chmod +x psipred").

Comment: As @ceving wrote you should try without `tcsh` - but try `./psipred ...` (note the first two chars).